# Looking for an automated aquarium

Tags: aquarium, fish, goldfish, cleaning, maintenance

I'm looking for a fully automated aquarium.

- Need an automatically timed feeder for the fish
- Could the aquarium could automatically clean itself
- A battery backup for both the feeder and the cleaning could be good too!

I'm not sure whether aquariums need any oxygen system or not. Also, not sure if it's safe to leave an aquarium with fishes un-managed when going on a holiday.

Normally I turn the electricity off before leaving, so that's the main reason for the battery backup.

If a battery powered aquarium is not available, then

- Is there any portable aquarium that's easy to carry?
- Also, some easier way to transfer the fishes from one aquarium to another?

I've tried a net, and it's scary to move the fishes to another aquarium with it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can I ask what sort of budget you have? It is possible to automate an aquarium, maybe not permanently, but definitely for long periods of time, but you're typically looking at costs well into the thousands just in electronics to manage it. If you're turning the power off completely, forget it, there's no reasonably cheap battery system designed to handle more than a few hours, after that it's generators, but none of these are a reasonable way to deliberately keep an aquarium going without power.

Comment: Ok. Then any way to carry the fish? I need to spend less than $100 for the aquarium and if it's not automatic, then maybe a portable one from to which the water doesn't flow off while traveling in a car. Thanks!

Comment: most aquariums are too fragile to be moved if full of water and if the aquarium can be moved by hand it is too small for you to have any fish in it.an automatic aquarium will make the experience of having and maintaining it yourself less enjoyable in my opinion.

Comment: ok. thanks! Would you suggest if buying birds would be a better decision when buying a pet?

Comment: no matter what type of pet you have in your care they will need daily interaction and care.birds and other caged animals are low maintenance but they need care every day.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you need is DVD of an Aquarium.  There are several varieties at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_12?url=search-alias%3Dmovies-tv&field-keywords=aquarium+dvd+for+tv&sprefix=Aquarium+dvd%2Cmovies-tv%2C152&crid=2KY3EF105R53Y) or [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xaquarium+dvd+for+tv.TRS0&_nkw=aquarium+dvd+for+tv&_sacat=0) as well as other retailers.

No feeding, no cleaning, and no worries.

Comment: Lol, I guess I'll buy birds then...

Comment: You should check out DVD's of birds then. If you're not interested in the cleaning out of your pets, you shouldn't have pets.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your budget you can pay a tank cleaning service to come to your house and do it. I used to do it and charged people $1 per gallon, I'd clean their tank, check the fish, and feed them if I was asked to. People would either have me come weekly or monthly depending on budget or schedule.

Comment: ok, I could try and find a tank cleaning service here, although the tank should only be cleaned once a month? I was guessing I could add automatic water cleanser and an automatic feeding device. Although, since I occasionally take a holiday, so was worried if the electricity goes off, then the automated digital stuff won't function... That's why I was looking for a completely automatic aquarium that could be connected to a good charged up UPS/battery.